# Python removing line from text file is removing everything

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove one line which matches a variable. But instead it is wiping the file clean.

```
                a_file = open("./Variables/TxtFile.txt", "r")
                lines = a_file.readlines()
                a_file.close()
                new_file = open("./Variables/TxtFile.txt", "w")
                for line in lines:
                    if line.strip("\n") == VariableStore:
                        new_file.write(line)
                        new_file.close()
```

The goal would be to remove the line that matches VariableStore rather than wiping the entire text file

Comment: Could it be that you only write the line you want to remove? Could be the case because you only write the file if the `if` condition is met and then close the file. You might want to change the `if` to `if not ...` and put the `close()` on the same level as the `for` loop.

Comment: The file has multiple lines containing different stuff, Instead just wiping the line that matches the variable, it wipes the text file to empty

Comment: You can only close the file once; after that you can't keep writing to it. Also, your logic says to write the line that matches. If you want to *remove* a line, that is the same as writing *every other line*, all the ones that *don't* match.

Comment: You should also try to look up how to use a `with` block to handle closing a file in Python.

Answer (score 1):

In regard to my comment to your original post.
You only write to the file if you match the line you want to remove and then also close the file.

This seems not to be what you want.

You might want to change the `if` condition to be executed in cases that do not match your line you want to remove, i.e., to `if not line.strip("\n") == VariableStore:` and close the file after your loop, i.e., on the same level as your `for` loop.

Try the following, which incorporates these suggestions:

```py
a_file = open("./Variables/TxtFile.txt", "r")
lines = a_file.readlines()
a_file.close()
new_file = open("./Variables/TxtFile.txt", "w")
for line in lines:
    if not line.strip("\n") == VariableStore:
        new_file.write(line)
new_file.close()
```

Comment: You should explain what is wrong with the original code, what you changed, and how that addresses the problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: sorry, my bad! I though it was clear from my comment to the OP, but you are right, a complete answer should have included that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to filter *out* the line matching `VariableStore`, do this:

```
with open("./Variables/TxtFile.txt", "r") as a_file:
    lines = a_file.readlines()

with open("./Variables/TxtFile.txt", "w") as new_file:
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip("\n") != VariableStore:
            continue  # Skip the VariableStore line
        new_file.write(line)  # Write other lines
```

When you use `with` statements, you don't need to manually close the file.

Comment: You should explain what is wrong with the original code, what you changed, and how that addresses the problem. Aside from the `with` block, I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to close the file later on, when you are done parsing all the lines.
Also, you need to write the lines that **don't** match, not the one's that do.
Note the changes below:

```
# Read file
a_file = open("./Variables/TxtFile.txt", "r")
lines = a_file.readlines()
a_file.close()
# Write file
new_file = open("./Variables/TxtFile.txt", "w")
for line in lines:
    if line.strip("\n") == VariableStore:
        # Don't write this line
        pass
    else:
        new_file.write(line)
new_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that your text file `TxtFile.txt` contains this text

```
Hello
World
I'm
Python
Developer
```

And you have a variable `var` contains the string `World` which we want to remove from the text file.

Here is a python code does the job in few lines

```
var='World' # a string to remove

with open("TxtFile.txt","r+") as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
   lines = [line for line in lines if line.strip()!=var]
   f.seek(0)
   f.writelines(lines)
   f.truncate()
```

The text file after running this code..

```
Hello
I'm
Python
Developer
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're opening the file with write mode instead of append mode. Replace

```
new_file = open("./Variables/TxtFile.txt", "w")
```

with

```
new_file = open("./Variables/TxtFile.txt", "a")
```

and you'll append the data instead of overwriting it.

Also, it's generally recommended to open files using the 'with' statement, since that automatically closes the file for you.

```
with open("./Variables/TxtFile.txt", "a") as text_file:
    ...
```